# Nvidia video card problems

Tags: nvidia

I have an Nvidia video card that is not working at full capacity and I need to use generic video drivers to install the linux. My computer is currently working with windows 10 although with generic drivers that does not allow me use the video card as full capacity. That is great since the video card does not work at all with the proper drivers. However I would like to try linux, but everytime I tried I fail. I tried ubuntu, puppy and linux mint and all of them fail. My questions is how can I install linux with generic video drivers or the same as windows?

Comment: Which model GPU do you have?

Answer (score 0):

just download Ubuntu and either burn onto a DVD or usb stick ... then boot up using this which will by default use the open source video drivers not Nividia ... this is a quick way to see of your machine is happy running Ubuntu ... If OK then do an install

Today this open source graphics driver ( Nouveau ) is robust and uses a very current OpenGL release ... in the ancient past only dedicated OEM drivers like Nvidia or AMD offered current OpenGL specs

Are you seeing Nouveau not giving you the most current OpenGL release your Nvidia graphics card supports ?

Once installed you can easily choose Nvidia drivers ... System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers ... give it a few seconds to list Nvidia drivers which you can cut over to

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 106.10 or 16.04 you may get a lopping problem when you reboot after installing these drivers, make sure you are using lightdm as the window manager, on your home directory, tye CTRL-H and look for file .Xauthority. Delete this file and then reboot, this is how I got passed the looping error.